# How to set IndexOption = docs

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I need to get result below with NEST (Elastic Search .NET client)

```
"detailVal": {
    "name": "detailVal",
    "type": "multi_field",
    "fields": {
        "detailVal": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "untouched": {               // <== FOCUS 2
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed",
            "omit_norms": true,
            "include_in_all": false,
            "index_options": "docs"  // <== FOCUS 1
        }
    }
}
```

I have done so far

```
    [ElasticProperty(OmitNorms = true, Index = FieldIndexOption.not_analyzed, IncludeInAll = false, AddSortField = true)]
    public string DetailVal { get; set; }
```

which gets me

```
"detailVal": {
    "name": "detailVal",
    "type": "multi_field",
    "fields": {
        "detailVal": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed",
            "omit_norms": true,
            "include_in_all": false
        },
        "sort": {                    // <== FOCUS 2
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
        }
    }
}
```

so, any idea how to

1. add **"index_options": "docs"**  *(I found IndexOptions.docs but it is not valid as Attribute)*
2. change **sort** to **untouched**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The attribute based mapping only gets you so far. It's good enough if you only need to change names and set simple properties.

The recommended approach is to use `client.MapFluent()`

See https://github.com/Mpdreamz/NEST/blob/master/src/Nest.Tests.Unit/Core/Map/FluentMappingFullExampleTests.cs#L129

For an example how to set `index_options`

And line 208:
https://github.com/Mpdreamz/NEST/blob/master/src/Nest.Tests.Unit/Core/Map/FluentMappingFullExampleTests.cs#L208

To see how you can create your own multi_field mapping.

You can even combine both approaches:

```
client.MapFluent<MyType>(m=>m
     .MapFromAttributes()
     //Map what you can't with attributes here
);
```

`client.Map()` and `client.MapFromAttributes()` will most likely be removed at some point.

Comment: @martjin-laaman thank you!  I'm already aware of the fluent syntax, but I don't want to give up attribute approach just for those 2 issues.  Thank you for your time again!

Comment: You can do both, call MapFromAttributes() inside MapFluent() and then only map what you can't otherwise.